# Why can't I add a Clocking Wizard to the block design?

Tags: tcl, vivado

I've been trying to develop an application using Microblaze as I did for months. But, somehow, Vivado's Block Design Tool doesn't let me either run the Block Automation Tool properly or add a Clocking Wizard manually. This is how the TCL console looks like when I try to add a Clocking Wizard manually.

```
startgroup
create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:clk_wiz:6.0 clk_wiz_0
FALSE
ERROR: [IP_Flow 19-3188] Error occurred while initializing 'design_1_clk_wiz_0_0'
Tcl error in update procedure while setting value 'MMCM' on the parameter 'PRIMITIVE'. FALSE

ERROR: [IP_Flow 19-3428] Failed to create Customization object design_1_clk_wiz_0_0
CRITICAL WARNING: [IP_Flow 19-5622] Failed to create IP instance 'design_1_clk_wiz_0_0'. Failed to customize IP instance 'design_1_clk_wiz_0_0'. Failed to load customization data
ERROR: [BD 41-1712] Create IP failed with errors
ERROR: [BD 5-7] Error: running create_bd_cell -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:clk_wiz:6.0 -type ip -name clk_wiz_0 .
ERROR: [Common 17-39] 'create_bd_cell' failed due to earlier errors.
endgroup
```

I also tried to continue the block design and then synthesis without a Clocking Wizard, you can see it below.
[image: Microblaze PS without a Clocking Wizard]

Unfortunately, it caused different errors than I expect. There are no meaningful errors under the Messages tab, and all I can see is that the Out-of-Context Module Run for the LMB BRAM had failed. You can also see the screen below.
[image: Out-of-Context Module Run Fails]

What do you think is wrong?

- **Vivado Version:** 2020.2
- **Operating System:** Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- **Part Name:** xc7a100tcsg324-1 *(I don't know if it is important)*

**EDIT:** I solved the problem by downgrading the Vivado version to 2017.4. I wish I could do that without reinstalling it

Comment: That looks like the error message is `FALSE` which is really weird (and totally uninformative from a general Tcl perspective, so I can't help more). One for your Vivado customer support channel?

Comment: @Donal Fellows Actually, I've shared the same question in Xilinx forums but couldn't get an answer yet.